# How to convert multiline string value to a legit JSON string variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This original code works fine.

```
function FetchNormal() {

    const [keyword, setKeyword] = React.useState(null);
    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const FetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setError(null)
                setIsLoading(true)
                const method = "POST"
                const headers = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                };
                const options = {
                    method,
                    headers
                };

                const body = {
                    query: "query GetWikicountByKeyword($keyword: String!)" +
                        "{ wikiCount                                      " +
                        "   (keyword: $keyword) {                         " +
                        "      keyword                                    " +
                        "      totalhits                                  " +
                        "    }                                            " +
                        "}                                                ",
                    variables : "{ \"keyword\": \"" + keyword +"\" }"
                };
                if (keyword == null) {
                    setResponse("No Result");
                } else {
                    if (body) options.body = JSON.stringify(body);
                    const res = await fetch(BASEURL, options);
                    const json = await res.json();
                    setResponse(json.data.wikiCount.keyword + ":" + json.data.wikiCount.totalhits);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error.toString());
                setResponse(null)
            }
            setIsLoading(false)
        };
        FetchData();
    }, [keyword]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div><SearchBox caption={"Normal Wiki Search"} onSubmit={(keyword) => setKeyword(keyword) }/></div>
            <div>
                {error &&  <SearchResult value={error} />}
                {isLoading ?
                    (<Loading />) :
                    (response && <SearchResult value={response}/>)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, I dislike the concatenate of String for `query`. So I change to below.

```
function FetchNormal() {
    const query = `
    query GetWikicountByKeyword($keyword: String!) {
        wikiCount
            (keyword: $keyword) {
                keyword 
                totalhits
            } 
    "}`.replace("\n", " ").trim()

    const [keyword, setKeyword] = React.useState(null);
    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const FetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setError(null)
                setIsLoading(true)
                const method = "POST"
                const headers = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                };
                const options = {
                    method,
                    headers
                };

                const body = {
                    query: query,
                    variables : "{ \"keyword\": \"" + keyword +"\" }"
                };

                if (keyword == null) {
                    setResponse("No Result");
                } else {
                    if (body) options.body = JSON.stringify(body);
                    const res = await fetch(BASEURL, options);
                    const json = await res.json();
                    setResponse(json.data.wikiCount.keyword + ":" + json.data.wikiCount.totalhits);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error.toString());
                setResponse(null)
            }
            setIsLoading(false)
        };
        FetchData();
    }, [keyword]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div><SearchBox caption={"Normal Wiki Search"} onSubmit={(keyword) => setKeyword(keyword) }/></div>
            <div>
                {error &&  <SearchResult value={error} />}
                {isLoading ?
                    (<Loading />) :
                    (response && <SearchResult value={response}/>)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But it now fail, as the newline kicks in and no matter how I try to remove it, it stays, causing wrong JSON format.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Your updated code seems to be missing the first lines. Please fix it to include the complete and valid code.

Comment: It seems the line `"}\`.replace("\n", " ").trim()` has extra double-quote `"`.

Comment: Are you sure it's the newlines being the source of the issue? What error message do you get? Afaics, newlines are totally valid, what causes problems (and is evidently different to your original code) is the addition of quotes around `query` (in `"\"" + query + "\""`).

Comment: Btw, much uglier than the `query` line concatenation is `variables : "{ \"keyword\": \"" + keyword +"\" }"`. This *really* should be `JSON.stringify({keyword})`, or actually there's no need to put a json text inside `variables`, just use `variables: { keyword },`!

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I have put in the full code for better context. The failure I got is from  server side stating no proper result. So I suspect it's multiline. I'm more than happy if multiline works, as long as I don't need to concat the string. As for the keyword, it is a variable to be set. If there's a better way to do it, I'll do it. I put the full code in that you have the concept. Thanks for checking! (I'm new to JavaScript)

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the tip. I check further, and found an extra `"` there. Fixing it works. As for the `keyword`, can you help see if this could be improve, since my `keyword` is literally constructed dynamically.

Comment: Ah, the line `const query = \`` was missing. And yes, like @senta said you also have a stray `"` in the last line of your template literal.

Comment: `variables: { keyword },` *does* take the dynamically constructed value into account.

Comment: Lovely. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad. Apparently I have an extra `"`

Replace this

```
    query GetWikicountByKeyword($keyword: String!) {
        wikiCount
            (keyword: $keyword) {
                keyword 
                totalhits
            } 
    "}`.replace("\n", " ").trim()
```

with

```
    query GetWikicountByKeyword($keyword: String!) {
        wikiCount
            (keyword: $keyword) {
                keyword 
                totalhits
            } 
    }`
```

Works now. Thanks!!